# Searching in three elements before and after a specific word in list

Tags: python, list

I have list of string, my main word is "any" and I want to search for the in any three words before or after the "any", I tried this:

```
list1 = ['I','love','any','kind','of','7up','as','drink']
soda = ['7up','pepsi','sprite','fanta']
fruit= ['orange','apple','banana','pineapple']

j = 0
while list1[j]:
    if list1[j] == 'any' and list1[j - 1:j - 3] == 'love':
        if list1[j + 1:j + 3] in soda:
            print "loving soda"
        elif list1[j + 1:j + 3] in fruit:
            print "loving fruit"
        else:
            pass
    j += 1
    if j == len(list1):
        break
```

I tried to slice the list and search in sliced list but it doesn't work for me, sometimes no output sometimes index out of range. I think there is better way to do it. I do not use builtin functions in my code but it fine if that would solve the problem. 
I want to check if any of three words before "any" in list1 and any three words after the word "any" in list1 that occur in any list soda or fruit

Comment: I have list of string, my main word is "any" and I want to search for the in any three words before or after the "any"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if any element in a slice meets some condition, use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) function with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

For example, instead of:

```
list1[j - 1:j - 3] == 'love'
```

use:

```
any(list1[i] == 'love' for i in xrange(j-1, j-3))
```

or:

```
any(e == 'love' for e in list1[j-1:j-3])
```

Comment: dear @augurar 
it does not work for me with this sentence "Fanta is better option than pepsi" I wanna work with "better" and "than" as a main words fro search around, I wanna check if they come together in the sentence  then check other words come after and before "better" and "than" and if I want to evaluate the sentence according to fanta i would say this is positive, and negative for pepsi, you can notice sometime pple don't write "better than" directly sometimes u can see "better choice than " and so on. hope u got the idea

Comment: @Ahmed My answer only addresses why expressions like `list1[j - 1:j - 3] == 'love'` in your code don't work.  If you want to learn more about how to parse human-generated text, you should study [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing).